# How do I run an HLA code in CMD that is written in Notepad++?

Tags: cmd, notepad++, command-prompt, hla

I am trying to run an HLA code in Command Prompt from a code I have written in Notepad++ but I'm not sure how to find the program in Command Prompt. How do I locate the program? I believe it should look something like this, but I'm not sure:

cd ....
cd hla

After this I am stuck. The file is in the hla folder on the Local Disk C and it is called hej.hla

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://flylib.com/books/en/1.332.1.7/1/) might help.

for windows: `hla hej.hla`

for Linux: `./hej`